# How to test a React Native App before going to production?

Tags: firebase, react-native, testflight, firebase-test-lab, firebase-app-distribution

Basically I've finished my beta React Native app, and I'm ready to test it with a private group of people, in order to know if it's stable and to correct possible bugs.

I am using firebase as a backend, so I am wondering if it's better to Firebase Test Lab and/or Firebase App Distribution or TestFlight (for the IOS).

I would like to know the advantages of this tools.

Answer (score 0):

https://appcenter.ms/ is pretty decent (Android)
for iOS you might want to use TestFlight (you need apple developer account

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Test Lab is not for app distribution. It is a way to determine if your app has quality issues prior to launch across a wide variety of devices.